# Can't manage to use tabs with Sherlock

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

Ok, so I'm trying to use Sherlock to display multiple tabs, each for one fragment.
I've got only 4classes : one for my main activity, two for my fragments, and one for the TabListener.
Everything should be ok (I've got quite the same program without Sherlcock, working on 4.0 devices), so I can't understand why i get that NullPointerException.

Here's part of the error

```
05-18 17:46:57.197: E/AndroidRuntime(9312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 17:46:57.197: E/AndroidRuntime(9312): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.micky.testing/com.micky.testing.SherlockTestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
05-18 17:46:57.197: E/AndroidRuntime(9312): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 17:46:57.197: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.micky.testing.MyTabListener.onTabSelected(MyTabListener.java:21)
...
05-18 17:46:57.197: E/AndroidRuntime(9312):     at com.micky.testing.SherlockTestActivity.onCreate(SherlockTestActivity.java:39)
```

Here is one of my fragment :
**HomeFragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class HomeFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.homefragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here is my tabListener :
**MyTabListener**

```
public class MyTabListener implements TabListener {

public SherlockFragment fragment;

MyTabListener(SherlockFragment fr) {
    Log.d("MYTAG", "Creating a fragmentListener w/ " + fr);
    this.fragment = fr;
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("TAG", "" + fragment);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}
```

}

And my main activity :
**SherlockTestActivity**

```
public class SherlockTestActivity extends SherlockActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //We take the support actionbar
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    //We set to navigationmode with tabs
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    //we create the tabs
    ActionBar.Tab homeTab = ab.newTab().setText("Home");
    ActionBar.Tab tagsTab = ab.newTab().setText("Tags");

    //We create the fragments
    SherlockFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    SherlockFragment tagsFragment = new TagFragments();

    //And we set the tabsListener;
    homeTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(homeFragment));
    tagsTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(tagsFragment));

    Log.d("","" + homeTab);
    ab.addTab(homeTab);
    ab.addTab(tagsTab);
}
```

Ok, so the error seems to be thrown when I add the tab to my actionbar. And when I don't add the TabListener to the tab, there's no error.
The code `ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);` (MyTabListener) seems to be the problem, but i can't manage to understand why. fragment isn't null (initialized when instanciating a new tabListener), and there's no reason the fragment_container is wrong.

So if anyone can manage to help me around here ! Thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be extending SherlockFragmentActivity instead of SherlockActivity. Use a fragment activity when you are managing fragments.

Comment: You actually shouldn't need your second point when using ABS. It should always give you a proper support-library transaction to use. If not, please file a bug!

Comment: I use ABS in my application and had to use this as a workaround. I'll try to test this out again sometime this weekend without the workaround and report back to you. I'm pretty sure I'm using 4.0.2

Comment: Alright, that was it. I didn't extend SherlockFragmentActivity, I should have seen it ! For the 2nd bug, it doesn't seem to be related to my problem (no error once I extend the SherlockFragmentActivity). Thanks !

Comment: I'll remove the 2nd portion of my answer for now since it may or may not be an actual bug (I know it was in the past). I'll try and help @JakeWharton out if this does seem to still be a bug with ABS. Otherwise, I'm simply doing something wrong on my end.